# How can I properly merge arrays into a 'tax_query' so I only get results of ALL filters instead of ANY in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm building a search and filter page. I've come to a problem. I have 9 filters. The user will select none, one, or any number of 9 of them at a time. I'm trying to avoid writing endless combinations of queries to satisfy each of those options.

I want to only show results of ALL of the filters together. This code works fine:

```
$taxquery= array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter1',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter2',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter3',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
);
```

What I'd really like is to do something like this. I gather the values from the `[GET]` paramaters earlier.

```
$mergedarrays= [];
if(isset($getfilter1result)){
$filter1= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter1',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
array_merge($mergedarrays, $filter1);
}
if(isset($getfilter2result)){
$filter2= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter2',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
array_merge($mergedarrays, $filter2);
}
if(isset($getfilter3result)){
$filter3= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'filter3',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
array_merge($mergedarrays, $filter3);
}
$taxquery= array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    echo $mergedarrays; //obviously this is not the right way to do this
);
```

I tried this way, but this resulted in ANY of the results being shown, rather than ALL of them.

```
$termsin= [];
if(isset($filter1)){
  $filter1= filtered1;
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter1);
}
if(isset($filter2)){
  $filter2= filtered2;
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter2);
}
if(isset($filter3)){
  $filter3= filtered3;
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter2);
}

$taxquery= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $termsin,
        'operator' => 'IN',
);
```

How can I get this to work correctly? Am I missing some basic function that could come in handy right around now? Seems to happen alot thanks to y'all showing me how to use the basic functions.

I use this in my `$args` array. Here's the main problem.

```
'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array('field1', 'field2'),
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            ),  
        ),
```

when I add this into my query, it shows results that match the terms `field1` OR `field2`. I need them to match both, so I'm asking is there a way to alter my wordpress query to make this happen?

Or do I need to write a different kind of code in PHP?

Comment: If you want ALL and not ANY, then IN is the wrong choice.  What do your slugs look like? Are you trying to match multiple substrings in a slug string?  We'd like a [mcve].

Comment: Great, that answered my question. DIdn't realize that `operator => 'AND'` was an option. that fixed it right up. Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using? We don't have that context anywhere on this page.

Comment: I'm editing in php, using the siteground web developer editor. I'm not sure what a framework is exactly, does that answer the question?

Comment: Is this application built on wordpress, laravel, etc.? Is it completely custom written?   We don't know how to construct the array of parameters because we don't know how the array is converted to sql.  There is a magic layer that we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks mickmackusa for giving me the idea.

Turns out I was using the wrong operator. Once I start using the operator 'AND', all the sudden my logic and code works. Thanks!

```
$termsin= [];
if(isset($filter1)){
  $filter1= 'filtered1';
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter1);
}
if(isset($filter2)){
  $filter2= 'filtered2';
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter2);
}
if(isset($filter3)){
  $filter3= 'filtered3';
  $termsin=$array_push($termsin, $filter2);
}

$taxquery= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'version-filter',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $termsin,
        'operator' => 'AND', //turns out I just needed to change this to 'AND'
);
```

Comment: In my actual code, they are tax slugs. I just type the name of the slug for that to work correctly. I forgot to put '' around each one, and have edited it in my code.